# Implementing IPluginExtraMenus for FogBugz using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, fogbugz

We are attempting to create a FogBugz plugin & have started naturally with the Hello World example [Wiki 38].

We are using Visual Studio 2005 and VB.Net.

However, whenever we add "Implements IPluginExtraMenus" to our class AND implement the appropriate function, Visual Studio reports that

> Class 'xxxx' must implement Function ExtrasMenuLinks() as UI.CNavMenuLink()
>   for interface FogCreek.FogBugz.Plugins.InterfacesIPluginExtrasMenu

Here is an example:

```
Public Class DaysRemaining
  Inherits Plugin
  Inherits IPluginPagedisplay
  Inherits IPluginExtrasMenu

  Public Function ExtrasMenuLinks() As UI.CNavMenuLink
    dim vMenu as CNavMenuLink
    vMenu = new CNavMenuLink("", "", "", "")
    Return vMenu
  End Function
End Class
```

Also, if we try and add an "Implements IPluginExtrasMenu.ExtrasMenuLinks" keyword in the function definition, Visual Studio reports that

> 'ExtrasMenuLinks' cannot implement 'ExtrasMenuLinks' because there is
>   no matching function on interface
>   FogCreek.FogBugz.Plugins.InterfacesIPluginExtrasMenu

We are importing all of the correct namespaces etc.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated e.g. pointing where we have gone wrong, pointing us in the direction of other VB.Net examples, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Visual Studio is complaining because interface expects ExtrasMenuLinks to return an array of UI.CNavMenuLink objects, whereas your implementation only returns a single UI.CNavMenuLink.

I believe the modification you need to make to match the interface is:

```
Public Function ExtrasMenuLinks() As UI.CNavMenuLink()
```

You'll also need to modify the function body to return an array.